# Jersey delivers an empty JSON

Tags: java, json, jersey

I'm working on a project for the university which makes me mad. I need to develop a webservice with jersey, but every request sends me just this empty JSON:

```
[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

The database query is test and delivers content. I just don't know what it could be.

Java:

```java
@Path("/getFachbereiche")
public class GetFachbereiche {
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Fachbereich[] getFachbereiche() {
        List<Fachbereich>fList = new ArrayList<Fachbereich>();
        Connection conn = MySQLConnection.getInstance();
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                // Anfrage-Statement erzeugen.
                Statement query;
                query = conn.createStatement();

                // Ergebnistabelle erzeugen und abholen.
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM Fachbereich";
                ResultSet result = query.executeQuery(sql);

                //Ergebniss zurückliefern
                while (result.next()) {
                    fList.add(new Fachbereich(result.getInt(1), result.getString(2)));
                }
            } catch(SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return fList.toArray(new Fachbereich[fList.size()]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your attributes from Fachbereich are private, by default, private attributes are not serialized.
You have two solutions :

- Put XmlElement annotation on each attribute so it will be serialized
- Or define a public getter for each attribute.